# Calling a stored procedure in mysql workbench is not returning values to the Result Grid

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct syntax but its not returning the movie_id, movie_name, leading_actor1_id leading_actor2_id or release_year to the Result Grid.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMoviesByActor(IN param_actor_id int(5))
BEGIN
    select movie_id, movie_name, leading_actor1_id, leading_actor2_id, release_year
    from movie
    where leading_actor1_id=param_actor_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;  

CALL sp_GetMoviesByActor(1)
```

I've tried other variations to call the result which didn't seem to work either. I'm using the latest version of mysql workbench and the connection seems to be fine since I'm able to retrieve other data from the query. I'm also not getting any errors when calling the procedure its just that the result grid doesn't return any data for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided for creating a stored procedure and calling it looks correct, assuming that your database schema and data are set up appropriately.
However, if you're not getting the expected results, here are a few things to check.

1. Add Error Handling, it will help you identify if there's an issue with data retrieval or other problems.

Sample Code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMoviesByActor(IN param_actor_id INT(5)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE no_data CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';

SELECT movie_id, movie_name, leading_actor1_id, leading_actor2_id, release_year
FROM movie
WHERE leading_actor1_id = param_actor_id;

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No data found for the given actor ID';
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

2. Check the MySQL server logs for any error messages or warnings related to the execution of the stored procedure. These logs can provide valuable information about what might be going wrong.
3. Confirm that you are connected to the correct database and schema in MySQL Workbench. If you are connected to the wrong schema or database, the procedure may not find the `movie` table.

   Use: `SELECT movie_id, movie_name, leading_actor1_id, leading_actor2_id, release_year FROM movie FROM [database].movie`

After considering these points, if you are still not getting the expected results, please provide more details about the database schema and data, as well as any error messages you are encountering, so that I can assist you further.